# MySQL Trigger to flag if one or two or neither columns have non null value set

Tags: mysql

I have a basic table; I have simplified it massively to make this clearer.

```
user
....
user_id
ref_id_1
ref_id_2
user_value
total_ref
```

The `ref_id_1` and `ref_id_2` can be optionally set, and I want the `total_ref` column to count if either or both `ref_id_1` and 2 are set. So if I create a record with `ref_id_2` set to 12, and `ref_id_1` is NULL then `total_ref` value should be 1.

If I update the record to set `ref_id_1` to 6 then the `total_ref` should be 2. If I update and remove a value and set it to NULL, then the total_ref should be 1. The value of the two ref's isn't important, only that they have a value set.

Is a trigger the best way to manage this? I need this as the total_ref will be used to split the total_value; if its 2, then I half it, if its 1 then I don't.

How would such a trigger be best implemented in MySQL? Or the alternative?

Comment: It sounds like a generated column might be a better solution than a trigger.

Comment: The expression would be `ref_id_1 IS NOT NULL + ref_id_2 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: ALTER TABLE user
ADD COLUMN `total_ref ` INT(1)
AS (`ref_id_1 IS NOT NULL + ref_id_2 IS NOT NULL`) STORED;

I tried this, but it isnt working, what appears to be my issue?

Comment: Do you have backticks around the entire expression? Backticks should just be around the column names.

Comment: Or just omit them entirely, since none of your column names are keywords that need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some kind assistance from @Barmar

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD COLUMN total_ref INT (1)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((ref_id_1 IS NOT NULL) + (ref_id_2 IS NOT NULL)) STORED;
```

The difference being the brackets (It was invalid without) and if I only use AS it didn't change the total_refs on an UPDATE.

Comment: I think that TINYINT datatype is enough. And data length is obviously excess (in recent versions its specifying is deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Use a generated column:

```
ALTER TABLE user
ADD COLUMN total_ref INT(1) AS (ref_id_1 IS NOT NULL + ref_id_2 IS NOT NULL);
```

Comparison operators return 1 or 0 depending on whether they're true or false, so you can add them like this to get the total.